# Is there a way to change the profile center URL?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, profile, php

In an email, if I want to redirect to a custom unsubscribe page, is there a way to change the value of the `%%profile_center_url%%` so that it goes to a new page instead of the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, however access to this is limited to Marketing Cloud Services and Support. You'll need to reach out to Support at **1-866-362-4538** to make this change for you.

https://www.marketingcloud.com/contact-us/